# How to select from 2 different tables and insert the values into a single table

Tags: mysql

Good day people. I would be very glad if someone puts me through this hassle.

I have three tables

employee:

```
id  firstname   lastname    birthdate
1     John       Smith      1976-01-02
2     Laura      Jones      1969-09-05
3     Jane       Green      1967-07-15
```

borrowed:

```
ref         book
 1        Simply SQL
 2        Ultimate HTML Reference
 3        Ultimate CSS Reference
 4        Art and Science of JavaScript
```

history:

```
Firstname          Book
```

**My question is this: How can i select the first name from table 1 and the book from table 2 and then insert the result into table 3.** 
I would be glad if this problem can be resolved for me cause it has really given me stress. Am new to mysql though. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `ref` column in the `borrowed` table relates to the employee ID in the first table, then you can join these tables and do an insert:

```
INSERT INTO history (Firstname, Book)
SELECT t1.firstname, t2.book
FROM employee t1
INNER JOIN borrowed t2
    ON t1.id = t2.ref
```

Comment: please how do i make ref column in the borrowed table relate to the employee id. Please just give me a hint am a real newbie here

Comment: My answer assumes that `ref` _already_ corresponds to the employee id.  If not, then my answer has no meaning, and your question may not have an answer.  Maybe post the full table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if there are no columns to join

```
insert into history (Firstname, Book) 
SELECT employee.firstname, borrowed.book 
FROM employee CROSS JOIN borrowed
```

Comment: This would be implying that _every_ employee borrowed _every_ book, which most likely is incorrect.

Comment: i agree. There are no proper columns to join. So i assumed he may be looking for Cartesian product.